# How does C++ make template deduction on rvalue reference?

Tags: c++, templates, rvalue-reference

```
template<typename T>
void foo(T&& arg);
```

I know if arg is an lvalue, e.g. `int x = 0; foo(x);` then `T = int&` and the function will be `foo(int& &&)`, which is `foo(int&)`.

if arg is an rvalue, e.g. `foo(0)`; then `T = int` and the function will be `foo(int&&)`.

What if I have

```
template<typename T>
void foo(T& arg);

template<typename U>
void bar(U&& u)
{
    foo(u);
}
```

What would be `T` in `foo` when calling `bar(0)`?

Comment: That can't compile. C++ doesn't allow to take a non-const reference to an rvalue (only const). Try `foo(0)`, it already fails: `error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘int&’ from an rvalue of type ‘int’`

Comment: Oh, I take it back. `foo(0)` fails to compile but `bar(0)` succeeds! And `bar` can modify it: http://ideone.com/t6Qvtn

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
template<typename U>
void bar(U&& u)
{
    foo(u);
}
```

Regardless of what you pass in to `bar`, `u` is an lvalue because it has a name.

`u` may be an lvalue reference or an rvalue reference, but when you pass it to `foo`, its "reference-ness" is ignored, as per usual.

Forget about lvalues and rvalues and templates for a moment. A reference is supposed to be an *alias* for another variable, and refering to a reference by name is supposed to behave, in most cases, just as if you were refering to the original variable:

```
int i = 42;
int& r = i;

f(int);
f(int&);
f(i); // error: call to ambiguous overload
f(r); // error: call to ambiguous overload

g(int);
g(r); // OK, pass by copy, reference-ness of r is irrelevant

h(int&);
h(i); // OK, pass by reference, non-reference-ness of i is irrelevant
```

In the function call statements above, the *id-expressions* `i` and `r` are lvalues of type `int`. The fact that the *variables* `i` and `r` are a non-reference and a reference respectively has no bearing on the type or value category of the corresponding *id-expressions*. This is the way references have always worked, and rvalue references don't change that.

```
template<typename T>
void foo(T& arg);
```

There is nothing you could pass to `foo` that would make `T` be a reference type. `arg` will always be an lvalue reference.

If you want to propagate the value category of an argument you need `std::forward`:

```
template<typename U>
void baz(U&& u)
{
    foo(std::forward<U>(u));
}

baz(42); // error: attempted to call foo() with an rvalue
```

Answer (score 1):

> What if I have

```
template<typename T>
void foo(T& arg);

template<typename U>
void bar(U&& u)
{
    foo(u);
}
```

> What would be T in foo when calling bar(0)?

It might sound a bit unexpected, but the use of an rvalue-reference is an lvalue expression, which means that `u` in `foo(u)` is an **lvalue** and it is perfectly fine to call a function that takes an lvalue-reference (in this case `foo`.

That is, for a call `bar(0)`, the specializations used would be:

```
bar<int>(int&&)
foo<int>(int&)
```

For `int value; bar(value);`, the specializations would be:

```
bar<int&>(int& &&) // i.e. int&
foo<int>(int&)
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be whatever U ends up being, so if U is an int it would be

```
bar(int&& u)
{
    foo(u);
}
```

passing an int into foo.

Comment: So T = int ? why not int&& ? u is int&&

Comment: Oooops, I thought you meant just the typename that gets passed in and not what the variable itself is, you will be passing int&&, but I believe the && part just references a place in memory rather than a type itself, T itself will be an int while what is passed into `foo` will be a reference.

Comment: @Ryan: the use of a variable that is an rvalue-reference is an lvalue expression.